# form with post method stops working when php extension is off

Tags: php

On my site I use htaccess url rewriting to remove php extensions completly from php files.

Php extension gets removed completly, /file.php maps to /file.

My problem is that php forms with POST method stop working when  remove php rule is active.

I am using :

```
 action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"
```

in action attribute of forms.

I am sure that this is not a htaccess or browser cache related issue because My htaccess regex is matching against both methods GET|POST. and I am using 302 to redirect.

My form url is /signup.php,  It chages to /signup when I type /signup.php, Do I need to replace PHP_SELF with /signup in action attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` rather than `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

Per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) (emphasis mine):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is

> The **filename** of the currently executing script, relative to
>   the document root.

whereas `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is

> The **URI** which was given in order to access this page;
>   for instance, '/index.html'.

Since you are rewriting your URLs to remove the .php extension, you should no longer refer to the script's filename, which contains the extension, but rather to the URI of the current page.

Comment: Thank you so much maxton. I just noticed that PHP_SELF failed to print the path on a rewritten url, PHP_SELF returned empty. that is why the form didnt work. I replaced it with "REQUEST_URI" its working fine now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Due to HTTP/1.1 regulations POST data cannot be carried through redirects. While there is a redirect code (307) which should allow POST data to be carried through a redirect, not all servers will support it due to potential security vulnerabilities.

Also note that both 302 and 307 are declared as "temporary" redirects, meaning that at some point in the future, it will not be, as such a cache control header should be sent indicating when it should check if it has been changed. The type of redirect you're doing here seems more like a permanent change, in which case a 301 should be sent.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

All of redirect issues aside, it's usually bad form (pun intended) for a form submission to hit any sort of redirects, as it appears 'phishy'. You should either submit directly to the page in question with: `<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>` or simply not provide an action attribute. As of HTML 5.0 the action attribute is not required http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp. If you want to follow HTML 4.0 standards `action=""` also works in the same manner, and is correct to the specifications (as the action is a relative url, a blank path means "here").

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method also

```php
htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], '.php'), ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply Changed my extension from .php to that file name.
for an instance:- xyz.php to xyz

$.ajax({
url: 'xyz',
data: formData,
method: 'POST',
beforeSend: function() {
$('.cb-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$("div.errors").css({ 'display': 'none'});
},